# Getting key-value combinations from a Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Let's suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> dic = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();

//.....
dic.Add("abc", new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
dic.Add("def", new string[] { "-", "!", ")" });
```

How can I get an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` containing the following combinations:

```
{
     { "abc", "1" },
     { "abc", "2" },
     { "abc", "3" },
     { "def", "-" },
     { "def", "!" },
     { "def", ")" }
}
```

It does not **have to** be a `Tuple<string, string>`, but it seemed to be the more appropiate type.

I was looking for a simple LINQ solution if there is any.

I have tried the following:

```
var comb = dic.Select(i => i.Value.Select(v => Tuple.Create<string, string>(i.Key, v)));
```

But `comb` ends up being of type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) which will flatten out your `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`:

```
var comb = dic.SelectMany(i => i.Value.Select(
                               v => Tuple.Create(i.Key, v)));
```

Which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

change your first (last to execute) `Select` to `SelectMany` to collapse the `IEnumerables`:

```
var comb = dic.SelectMany(i => i.Value.Select(v => Tuple.Create(i.Key, v)));
//returns IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution also uses SelectMany, but may be slightly more readable:

```
var pairs =
  from kvp in dictionary
  from val in kvp.Value
  select Tuple.Create<string, string>(kvp.Key, val)
```